# Time bands in a column in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

Take Datetime and give the half hour band it belongs to, irrespective of the date, just interested in the time.

There is as far as I can see, no time periods in SSRS, I need half hour time periods, that's 48 blocks in a day.

I would like to plot my data in bar chart,the interval for the bar width is along the x axis, the height is the occurrences on the y axis. I need an interval of half hour(the width of the histogram),I don't want to run some IIF/CASE statement, I would rather, convert the DateTime i have to a band on each row of data, what's the best way to output so I get half hour intervals along the X axis.

Comment: Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a question.  You are severely lacking information in the question around the data structure and source at this point. Try to build the bar chart in SSRS, tell us what you've done and where you are currently stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to run some IIF/CASE statement

By this I assume you mean you don't want 48 layers of `IIF`/`CASE`. Here's an SSRS expression that'll band a datetime just using a single `IIF`:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, 0-
IIF(Minute(Fields!DATETIMEFIELD.Value) <= 29, Minute(Fields!DATETIMEFIELD.Value), Minute(Fields!DATETIMEFIELD.Value) -30),
DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 0-Second(Fields!DATETIMEFIELD.Value) ,Fields!DATETIMEFIELD.Value))
```

This removes the seconds from the time, and removes as many minutes necessary to get to the previous half-hour. You could likely use the same logic with different syntax as a column in your SQL query, if you prefer.

Use this calculated value for all the relevant parts of your SSRS chart.

Comment: This is what I have at the moment =IIf(Fields!TimeBandHour.Value<30,"00",(DatePart("h", Fields!Time.Value)&":"& 30 &"-"&FormatDateTime(DateAdd("h", 1,Fields!Time.Value), DateFormat.ShortTime )))

Comment: IF the time was 11.45 it gives 11.30-12.45, not quite right. The time Band hour, is just the hours and minutes of the dateTimeValue,